# How to find the cumulative sum of every previous n elements in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of integers:
`list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`
I am trying to figure how to sum every previous 3 elements with a skip of 3 between them:
`new list = [1+2+3,4+5+6,7+8+9] = [6,15,24]`
I've tried to convert the list to a `pandas series` by using the following:
`new_series.rolling(window=3).sum()`
but that doesn't seem to work.
I wonder what is the best approach here?
Thanks!

Comment: How would this work if the length of the list is not divisble by 3?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh From the given list, which is of length 10, I'm guessing OP would want to drop the last `len(list)%3` elements. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[sum(my_list[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,3*(len(my_list)//3),3)]
```

If the list has a length which is a multiple of 3 this can be shortened to

```
[sum(my_list[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(my_list),3)]
```

Comment: @John We could try `[sum(l[i-3: i]) for i in range(3, len(l), 3)]`, where `l` is `my_list`, to reduce a few arithmetic ops.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
new_list = []
for i in range(0, (len(list)), 3):
    new_list.append(sum(list[i:i + 3]))
if len(list) % 2 == 0 : new_list.pop()
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    
print([sum(arr[i-3:i]) for i in range(3, len(arr), 3)])
```

Comment: Wow that was really quick answer!
unfortunately the result yields the following:   
```python
print([sum(new_list[:i]) for i in range(1, len(new_list) + 1)])
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work, you need a step of 3 in the for loop, (the last argument)

```py
 def sumOfPrevious3(list):
    res = []
    for i in range(2, len(list), 3):
        res.append(list[i] + list[i-1] + list[i-2])
    return res
 print(sumOfPrevious3([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])) # [6, 15, 24]
```

or the same function but less readable

```py
def sumOfPrevious3(list):
    return [sum(list[i-2:i+1]) for i in range(2, len(list), 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) solution:

```
import numpy as np

list_ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
np.array(list_).reshape((3,-1)).sum(axis=1)
```

which gives:

```
[ 6, 15, 24]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is yet another way of doing it

```
>>> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> it=iter(arr)
>>> list(map(sum,zip(it,it,it)))
[6, 15, 24]
>>>
```